# Jmeter with multipart/form-data

Tags: jmeter

In Jmeter i wanted to prepare multipart/form-data by using JSR223 PreProcessor groovy

i try using
vars.put("formData", formData) like this

```
import org.apache.http.entity.ContentType
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntityBuilder
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.FileBody
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.StringBody
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils

def filePath = "path/to/file"
def file = new File(filePath)

def payload = "some payload"

def builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create().setCharset(java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.UTF_8)

builder.addPart("payload", new StringBody(payload, ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN))
builder.addPart("file", new FileBody(file, ContentType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM, file.name))

def formData = builder.build()

vars.put("formData", formData)
```

and got error "No signature of method: org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterVariables.put() is applicable for argument types: (String, org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartFormEntity)"
what should i do if i want to prepare multipart/form-data in script and then using it in HTTP Request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `vars` stands for [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class instance. [`vars.put()`](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html#put(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)) function assumes that the 2nd argument is a [String](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/String.html) and you're trying to pass something else. If this is what you want you should use [`vars.putObject()`](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html#putObject(java.lang.String,java.lang.Object)) instead. Or you need to convert the entity into a String first somehow
2. I don't think you need to do this in Groovy at all, you can perform the multipart request using normal JMeter's [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler, you can put the "payload" into request parameters and the file to "Files Upload" and tick `Use multipart/form-data` box:

   [image]

   It also can be done programmatically using `sampler` shortcut for the [HTTPSamplerProxy](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/http/sampler/HTTPSamplerProxy.html) class

See [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-java-classes) article for more information on the above and other JMeter API shorthands available for the JSR223 test elements